# FailedPreconditionError during restoring tensorflow CNN model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I am using following code to train and save my model:

```
def _random_selection(test, target, batch_size):
    examples, labels = zip(*random.sample(list(zip(test, target)), batch_size))
    return (np.array(examples), labels)

#Input pipeline is to get random images from
#test or train data.
def input_pipeline(batch_size, test):
    if test:
        return _random_selection(X_test, y_test, batch_size)
    return _random_selection(X_train, y_train, batch_size)
 #train and test data are read from files and stored in array.

def cnn_model(input_images, batch_size):
    def truncated_normal_var(name, shape, dtype):
        return (tf.get_variable(name=name, shape=shape, dtype=dtype,
                                initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.05)))

    def zero_var(name, shape, dtype):
        return (tf.get_variable(name=name, shape=shape, dtype=dtype, initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0)))

    # First Convolutional Layer
    with tf.variable_scope('conv1') as scope:
        # Conv_kernel is 5x5 for all 1 channel and we will create 64 features
        conv1_kernel = truncated_normal_var(name='conv_kernel1', shape=[5, 5, 3, 64], dtype=tf.float32)
        # We convolve across the image with a stride size of 1
        conv1 = tf.nn.conv2d(input_images, conv1_kernel, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
        # Initialize and add the bias term
        conv1_bias = zero_var(name='conv_bias1', shape=[64], dtype=tf.float32)
        conv1_add_bias = tf.nn.bias_add(conv1, conv1_bias)
        # ReLU element wise
        relu_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv1_add_bias)

    # Max Pooling
    pool1 = tf.nn.max_pool(relu_conv1, ksize=[1, 3, 3, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME', name='pool_layer1')
    # Local Response Normalization
    norm1 = tf.nn.lrn(pool1, depth_radius=5, bias=2.0, alpha=1e-3, beta=0.75, name='norm1')

    # Second Convolutional Layer
    with tf.variable_scope('conv2') as scope:
        # Conv kernel is 5x5, across all prior 64 features and we create 64 more features
        conv2_kernel = truncated_normal_var(name='conv_kernel2', shape=[5, 5, 64, 64], dtype=tf.float32)
        # Convolve filter across prior output with stride size of 1
        conv2 = tf.nn.conv2d(norm1, conv2_kernel, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
        # Initialize and add the bias
        conv2_bias = zero_var(name='conv_bias2', shape=[64], dtype=tf.float32)
        conv2_add_bias = tf.nn.bias_add(conv2, conv2_bias)
        # ReLU element wise
        relu_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2_add_bias)

    print("relu_conv2 shape " + `relu_conv2.get_shape()`)

    # Max Pooling
    pool2 = tf.nn.max_pool(relu_conv2, ksize=[1, 3, 3, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME', name='pool_layer2')
    # Local Response Normalization (parameters from paper)
    norm2 = tf.nn.lrn(pool2, depth_radius=5, bias=2.0, alpha=1e-3, beta=0.75, name='norm2')

    # Reshape output into a single matrix for multiplication for the fully connected layers
    reshaped_output = tf.reshape(norm2, [batch_size, -1])
    reshaped_dim = reshaped_output.get_shape()[1].value

    # First Fully Connected Layer
    with tf.variable_scope('full1') as scope:
        # Fully connected layer will have 384 outputs.
        full_weight1 = truncated_normal_var(name='full_mult1', shape=[reshaped_dim, 384], dtype=tf.float32)
        full_bias1 = zero_var(name='full_bias1', shape=[384], dtype=tf.float32)
        full_layer1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(reshaped_output, full_weight1), full_bias1))

    # Second Fully Connected Layer
    with tf.variable_scope('full2') as scope:
        # Second fully connected layer has 192 outputs.
        full_weight2 = truncated_normal_var(name='full_mult2', shape=[384, 192], dtype=tf.float32)
        full_bias2 = zero_var(name='full_bias2', shape=[192], dtype=tf.float32)
        full_layer2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(full_layer1, full_weight2), full_bias2))
    # Final Fully Connected Layer -> 10 categories for output (num_targets)

    with tf.variable_scope('full3') as scope:
        # Final fully connected layer has 10 (num_targets) outputs.
        full_weight3 = truncated_normal_var(name='full_mult3', shape=[192, num_targets], dtype=tf.float32)
        full_bias3 = zero_var(name='full_bias3', shape=[num_targets], dtype=tf.float32)
        final_output = tf.add(tf.matmul(full_layer2, full_weight3), full_bias3)

    return (final_output)


def training_loss(logits, targets):
    # Get rid of extra dimensions and cast targets into integers
    targets = tf.squeeze(tf.cast(targets, tf.int32))
    # Calculate cross entropy from logits and targets
    cross_entropy = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, labels=targets)
    # Take the average loss across batch size
    cross_entropy_mean = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy)
    return (cross_entropy_mean)


def train_step(loss_value, generation_num):
    # Our learning rate is an exponential decay (stepped down)
    model_learning_rate = tf.train.exponential_decay(learning_rate, generation_num, num_gens_to_wait, lr_decay,
                                                     staircase=True)
    # Create optimizer
    my_optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(model_learning_rate)
    # Initialize train step
    train_step = my_optimizer.minimize(loss_value)
    return (train_step)


def accuracy_of_batch(logits, targets):
    # Make sure targets are integers and drop extra dimensions
    targets = tf.squeeze(tf.cast(targets, tf.int32))
    # Get predicted values by finding which logit is the greatest
    batch_predictions = tf.cast(tf.argmax(logits, 1), tf.int32)
    # Check if they are equal across the batch
    predicted_correctly = tf.equal(batch_predictions, targets)
    # Average the 1's and 0's (True's and False's) across the batch size
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(predicted_correctly, tf.float32))
    return (accuracy)

images, targets = input_pipeline(batch_size, test=False)
test_images, test_targets = input_pipeline(batch_size, test=True)
```

with tf.variable_scope('model_definition') as scope:
    # Declare the training network model
    model_output = cnn_model(images, batch_size)
    scope.reuse_variables()
    # Declare test model output
    test_output = cnn_model(test_images, batch_size)

```
loss = training_loss(model_output, targets)
accuracy = accuracy_of_batch(test_output, test_targets)
generation_num = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False)
train_op = train_step(loss, generation_num)

init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess.run(init)
tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess)

train_loss = []
test_accuracy = []
for i in range(generations):
    sess.run([train_op, loss])

saver = tf.train.Saver()
save_path = saver.save(sess, "./tf.train.save")
```

In the following code, I am restoring it

```
saver = tf.train.Saver()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    saver.restore(sess, "tf.train.save")
    init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
    sess.run(init)
    tf.initialize_all_variables()
    with tf.variable_scope('model_definition') as scope:
        output = cnn_model(imgs, batch_size)
    #To get variable value.
    sess.run(output)
```

When I run the code to restore the model, I got following error:

```
File "restore_tf.py", line 154, in <module>
    sess.run(output)
  File "/home/devender/code/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 905, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/home/devender/code/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1137, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "/home/devender/code/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1355, in _do_run
    options, run_metadata)
  File "/home/devender/code/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1374, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value model_definition/full3/full_bias3_1
     [[Node: model_definition/full3/full_bias3_1/read = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@model_definition/full3/full_bias3_1"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](model_definition/full3/full_bias3_1)]]

Caused by op u'model_definition/full3/full_bias3_1/read', defined at:
  File "restore_tf.py", line 151, in <module>
    output = cnn_model(imgs, batch_size)
  File "restore_tf.py", line 127, in cnn_model
    full_bias3 = zero_var(name='full_bias3', shape=[num_targets], dtype=tf.float32)
  File "restore_tf.py", line 64, in zero_var
    return (tf.get_variable(name=name, shape=shape, dtype=dtype, initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0)))
  File "/home/devender/code/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 1297, in get_variable
    constraint=constraint)
  File "/home/devender/code/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 1093, in get_variable
    constraint=constraint)
  File "/home/devender/code/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 439, in get_variable
    constraint=constraint)
  File "/home/devender/code/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 408, in _true_getter
    use_resource=use_resource, constraint=constraint)
  File "/home/devender/code/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 800, in _get_single_variable
    use_resource=use_resource)
  File "/home/devender/code/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 2157, in variable
    use_resource=use_resource)
  File "/home/devender/code/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 2147, in <lambda>
    previous_getter = lambda **kwargs: default_variable_creator(None, **kwargs)
  File "/home/devender/code/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 2130, in default_variable_creator
    constraint=constraint)
  File "/home/devender/code/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py", line 233, in __init__
    constraint=constraint)
  File "/home/devender/code/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py", line 381, in _init_from_args
    self._snapshot = array_ops.identity(self._variable, name="read")
  File "/home/devender/code/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 131, in identity
    return gen_array_ops.identity(input, name=name)
  File "/home/devender/code/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 2051, in identity
    "Identity", input=input, name=name)
  File "/home/devender/code/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/devender/code/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3271, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/devender/code/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1650, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

FailedPreconditionError (see above for traceback): Attempting to use uninitialized value model_definition/full3/full_bias3_1
 [[Node: model_definition/full3/full_bias3_1/read = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@model_definition/full3/full_bias3_1"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](model_definition/full3/full_bias3_1)]]
```

What is missing here to restore variables from files?

Comment: You don't need `sess.run(init)` in restore because it clears all restored variables